# autoresize in angular primeng throw error

Tags: angular, textarea, primeng, autoresize

when I try to use the autoresize attribut, i have one error:
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`

the template code is :
`<textarea [rows]="5" [cols]="30" id="float-input3" pInputTextarea autoResize="true"></textarea>`

I use this attribute like in the documentation, i don’t know what is not working.

I have already try to use `autoResize="autoResize"` but I have the same error.

the documentation https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/inputtextarea

Do you know what is not working or what I am not doing correctly ?

I use Primeng 11.2.0 and Angular 11.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you need to add a new public property to your component:

```
public autoResize: boolean = true;
```

...and then bind it into the template like:

```
<textarea ... [autoResize]="autoResize"></textarea>
```

In your examples you didn't have the `[  ]` around the property. Angular was getting confused as to whether you wanted to pass `"true"` as a string or `true` as a boolean. When it is explicitly defined in the component with `:boolean`, angular can be assured of what the type is.

Comment: I'm sure I tried and it didn't work. 
But here it works, I might have had to restart the server.
Thanks Zze

Comment: @Dave I made a small update to the post. I am glad that you have it working though!